# Chrome scrollWidth is different on rtl and ltr direction

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, user-interface

I see a bug on google chrome.
run the below html code on `Chrome V 31`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chrome scrollWidth issue</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="direction: ltr;">
  <div style="overflow: auto; height: 100px; width: 800px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style="height: 150px; width: 1080px; background: blue;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I change the body direction from `ltr` to `rtl`, the `scrollWith` of the parent div is different.
This is not occurred on `FireFox V25` or `Internet Explorer V10`.

I report the issue on [chrome issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=scrollWidth&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=330970).

**My question is how can I fix this with css or javascript?**

Comment: I duplicated the error. Interesting... I wasn't on the parent div previously. I'm curious... They look and react the same.. what was the issue that this caused for you?

Comment: @Phlume We use Sencha ExtJs in our team and I see the issue on resizing grid component when it is in rtl mode, then I faced that this is on calculating with of columns, finally I found this bug on google chrome v 31!

Comment: @OmidShariati i am also using Chrome V 31 i dont get your problem. It is working fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use clientWidth in the child element and you'll get 1080 in both rtl and ltr, hope that's a good enough solution till they fix the bug on chrome.

Answer (score -2):

Add this on parent `div`'s CSS

```
float:left
```